# SWIG Python wrapping, strange in divide operator overload

Tags: python, c++, overloading, swig, built-in

When I wrap a special math operation, I try to wrap the following overloaded operator in class CTPS:

```
inline const CTPS operator+(const CTPS & M) const {return CTPS(*this)+=M;}
inline const CTPS operator+(const double & a) const {return CTPS(*this)+=a;}
inline const CTPS operator-(const CTPS & M) const {return CTPS(*this)-=M;}
inline const CTPS operator-(const double & a) const {return CTPS(*this)-=a;}
inline const CTPS operator-() const {return CTPS(*this)*=(-1);}
inline const CTPS operator+() const {return CTPS(*this);}

inline const CTPS operator/(const CTPS & M) const {return CTPS(*this)/=M;}
inline const CTPS operator/(const double & a) const {return CTPS(*this)/=a;}
inline const CTPS operator*(const CTPS & M) const {return CTPS(*this)*=M;}
inline const CTPS operator*(const double & a) const {return CTPS(*this)*=a;}
```

with the following rename rules in SWIG:

```
%rename (__add__) operator+;
%rename (__sub__) operator-;
%rename (__div__) operator/;
%rename (__mul__) operator*;

%rename (__neg__) operator-();
%rename (__pos__) operator+();
```

I tried both with/without -builtin option of SWIG.  In python, the divide operator does not work in builtin mode but works without this option. Could anyone explain what I have done wrong with this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe not use rename function and just use new version of swig, which can support corresponding Python version. I have meet the same question that operator/ overload of class in C++ was wrapped by swig2.0, but python3.7 have not identified operator/ of class in C++.  By replaceing the swig version which can supprot python3.7, my question was resolved at last.